# How do I make apache SNI hosts without certificates redirect to http address?

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, sni

I have an apache server with multiple named hosts all working fine for port 80 http traffic. 
(A VPS with one unique IP address)

I have one domain that has a SSL certificate and that domain is configured to handle both http and https traffic.

However if someone accidentally adds https to the beginning of a none SSL configured URL I get a typical certificate warning error (expected) and then if the user accepts the error (depending on the browser) it displays the SSL site I have configured instead of the original non-ssl domain.

I've read up a bit about SNI, but I don't have certificates for each of the other domains and would rather the server either not respond to the SSL request on anything else but one specific domain or redirect to the http version of the site.

Suggestions please as to how I approach this.

Kind regards, Spencer

Comment: Possibly more suitable on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, what you're trying to achieve cannot work.

The browser (which implements the mechanisms to check the certificate) cannot know whether the user typed `https://` instead of `http://` accidentally or intentionally. Since it's ultimately up to the users to check that `https://` is used when they think it's required, browsers should simply perform the actions requested by the users.

A redirection from `https://` to `http://` should always start with a valid `https://` connection. SNI won't help you much there if you can't have valid certificates for the initial connection.

Otherwise, it would be fair for browsers to assume there may be a MITM attack in progress. Typing in `https://` explicitly (or using HSTS) is the only reliably mechanism against MITM tools like SSLstrip, which would otherwise be capable of downgrading (or preventing an upgrade from `http://` to `https://`).